# Browserify getting correct error line numbers

Tags: gruntjs, browserify

I'm using browserify to compile react and react-router amongst some other libraries. When an error occurs at runtime the browser is pointing to the wrong line, which often leaves me with really cryptic messages and not much else to work with. It's driving me nuts. How can I solve this?

For example

```
Invariant Violation: Unrecognized route configuration element "<UnknownComponent>"
```

Points halfway in this comment

```
/**
 * Hyphenates a camelcased CSS property name, for example:
 *
 *   > hyphenateStyleName('backgroundColor')
 *   < "background-color"
 *   > hyphenateStyleName('MozTransition')
 *   < "-moz-transition"
 *   > hyphenateStyleName('msTransition')
 *   < "-ms-transition"
 *
```

In my grunt browserify task configuration I have enabled debugging

```
vendor: {
  src: [],
  dest: 'assets/js/dependencies/vendor.js',
  options: {
    debug: true,
    require: ['react', 'react-router', 'material-ui']
  },
  browserifyOptions: {
    debug: true
  }
},
```

What else can I do?